# Spring boot - Unable to build hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere

I am getting this runtime exception when I deploy my war file on IBM Websphere 8.5.5.14/ SDK 1.8 on a local machine. However, no such exception is encountered when I deploy the same app on Tomcat.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>xyz</name>
    <description>Web App</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.8.2</log4j2.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.13.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initializer.enabled=true
server.session.timeout=600
```

spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql

**Stack Trace**

```
[12/10/18 11:30:37:536 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: Error creating bean with name &amp;#39&#59;entityManagerFactory&amp;#39&#59; defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed&amp;#59&#59; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory&amp;#59&#59; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[12/10/18 11:30:37:536 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:433)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:536 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1450)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1032)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:537 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5572)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5698)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:538 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:91)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:539 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:628)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:540 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:541 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:968)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:515)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:336)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:542 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:543 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:544 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:544 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:544 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:544 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:544 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:544 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: Error creating bean with name &amp;#39&#59;entityManagerFactory&amp;#39&#59; defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed&amp;#59&#59; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory&amp;#59&#59; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[12/10/18 11:30:37:544 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:914)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:545 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    ... 96 more
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Error creating bean with name &#39;entityManagerFactory&#39; defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed&#59; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory&#59; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:186)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    ... 98 more
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:546 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:156)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:136)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:547 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:620)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    ... 99 more
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    ... 120 more
[12/10/18 11:30:37:548 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.suspend(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:131)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:51)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.buildDdlTransactionIsolator(JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.java:46)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:178)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:94)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384)
[12/10/18 11:30:37:549 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R    ... 124 more
```

**Note** : I have made the class loading policy to PARENT_LAST.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to the exception?

Comment: Can you remove <hibernate.version>5.2.13.Final</hibernate.version> from pom let parent/JPA handle auto and also remove mysql connector version as spring boot will auto manage versions..

Comment: @DavidD Added, please check.

Comment: Can you check with let parent manage all hibernate and mysql connector dependency and check if it works fine as seems jar conflict issue..

Comment: @kj007 Thanks a lot man it worked, you saved me !!

Comment: @ParagKadam you are welcome, I have posted my answer..please accept if it helps you to solve problem..

Comment: @kj007 Can you take a look at this as well as they are somewhat related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779701/spring-boot-with-websphere-8-5-5-uowmanager-transaction-processing-failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot version `1.5.15.RELEASE` has dependency of Hibernate is `<hibernate.version>5.0.12.Final</hibernate.version>`.

So removing  `<hibernate.version>5.2.13.Final</hibernate.version>` from your pom and let Spring boot download compatible version with it should solve the problem.

after this clean install dependencies and generate war.

and also remove version of mysql connector(`<version>5.1.8</version>`):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>         
</dependency>
```