# Spring boot with websphere 8.5.5 - UOWManager transaction processing failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere

I am getting this exception when the web app is started(Via URL), it seems to be JTA dependency issue but I am unable to fix it. This works on Tomcat but fails on Websphere.

**Stack trace**

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: UOWManager transaction processing failed; nested exception is com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: java.lang.LinkageError: com/ibm/websphere/uow/UOWSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization(Ljavax/transaction/Synchronization;)V (loaded from file:/home/parag/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@52adb42a) called from class org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter (loaded from file:/home/parag/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/parag-desktopNode01Cell/eplvc-0_0_5_war.ear/eplvc-0.0.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@b0248555[appwar:eplvc-0_0_5_war]

Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@e95e3a61
   Delegation Mode: PARENT_LAST).
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:300) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:301) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811) [na:2.9 (07-25-2018)]
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: java.lang.LinkageError: com/ibm/websphere/uow/UOWSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization(Ljavax/transaction/Synchronization;)V (loaded from file:/home/parag/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@52adb42a) called from class org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter (loaded from file:/home/parag/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/parag-desktopNode01Cell/eplvc-0_0_5_war.ear/eplvc-0.0.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@b0248555[appwar:eplvc-0_0_5_war]

Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@e95e3a61
   Delegation Mode: PARENT_LAST).
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:812) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:370) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:293) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: com/ibm/websphere/uow/UOWSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization(Ljavax/transaction/Synchronization;)V (loaded from file:/home/parag/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@52adb42a) called from class org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter (loaded from file:/home/parag/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/parag-desktopNode01Cell/eplvc-0_0_5_war.ear/eplvc-0.0.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@b0248555[appwar:eplvc-0_0_5_war]

Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@e95e3a61
   Delegation Mode: PARENT_LAST).
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:387) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:791) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted

**Class path excluded for the sake of brevity and can be provided if required.**
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.iciciprulife.eplvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>eplvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>eplvc</name>
    <description>ICICI Pru Life ePLVC</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.8.2</log4j2.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eplvc?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initializer.enabled=true
server.session.timeout=600
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql
```

Comment: Do you have a JTA API in your app? LinkageErrors are usually caused by duplicate visibility of some class between two class loaders (in most cases a Parent Last application and the server). It's unlikely that you really NEED your own transaction API, so consider removing that and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: might be conflict with JPA, Change the classloader to Parent First or remove the duplicate jars?? as seems you have defined Parent LAST as i saw your last post..

Comment: Can you please run mvn clean install then generate war.as might be you cached jta..

Comment: you pom does not have jta dependency so I am afraid you are using jta trasnactions as its conflicting org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager with JPA so if you are not using jta then cleaning your project and load dependencies by clean should remove jta cached jar from your project..

Comment: If mvn clean install does not clear out caches then remove your .m2 repository and reinstall again should work

Comment: I can see the JTA jar file in my class path, but I have not put any JTA dependency explicitly in pom.xml. It looks like the JTA jar file came from the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency.

Comment: I cannot make classloader to parent first or it is only going to give me more issues.

Comment: `mvn clean install` does not remove the cached jar, i will remove .m2 repository and see if it works.

Comment: @kj007 Removing .m2 repository and then doing `mvn clean install` will again put the JTA dependency in the classpath and hence it's giving the same error.

Comment: @Jarid Yes, I don't need JTA API, but then how do I remove it since I am not explicitly putting it in my pom.xml, It is coming from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` which cannot be removed. And `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` seems to somehow depend on JTA and its loading the JTA API implicitly.

Comment: @ParagKadam seems the issue is WebSphere does provide the same class file in the j2ee.jar which is conflicting with JPA's jta jar and as you are using parent last so its first picking webspere jar creating conflict..

Comment: Yes, WebSphere does provide the same class, and not just that it forces to use their Transaction API over Spring's own Transaction API and since I have mentioned PARENT_LAST as the class loading policy it uses the Spring's Transaction API which is causing the problem.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cspr_data_access_tran1.html here it shows how to deal with the problem, and right now I am not able to understand how I can modify my code to accomodate the changes mentioned in the article. If you understand what the article says please let me know.

Comment: Can you see this if it can help https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/177779/jta-linking-error-on-was-85-network-deployment/ not much aware with websphere configuration..PARENT_FIRST will load spring jpa's class so if there is no impact then try with PARENT_FIRST..

Comment: Well from my reading so far, PARENT_FIRST will load the resources from WAS not from the Application, and making PARENT_FIRST will have a huge impact and cause other issues. The article that I shared should help but I am not understanding how I can implement it in my project being a Spring boot newbie.

Comment: can you try by removing jta jar from webspahere's installed_path/lib folder so it can load from application classpath..not sure if its there or look at article to put logs from where its trying to load ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181869/discussion-between-kj007-and-parag-kadam).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this adding `-Dspring.jta.enabled=false` in the Generic JVM arguments in Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine in the Websphere console.